# Git and PhpStorm project play together

Tags: git, version-control, phpstorm

I am trying to understand how to work with Git and PhpStorm together.

Lets imagine situation, I have an APP in a local git repo in folder `some_project`, so in git meaning this is will be a working area .git folder inside with. In repository I have 2 branches `master` and `develop` which equal for this moment.

So now I implement some new future in my APP, to do this I am making new branch with name, say, `new_future`. After that I am checkout `new_future` and ready to go do some work.

Now, I faced with certain questions:

1. Where I must to create PhpStorm project? Do I need to create it in repository folder? Cause if I will create it in repo folder then while changing branch with checkout using GIT my project files will be changed, do I need this? And after all, if I will delete project using PhpStorm - I could delete my all repository! This is unacceptable!
2. So if I will create project in other folders out my repo then how I will get code from my branch `new_future`? How I will commit and so on? Cause my project will be out of SVC folder and to do this all I guess need to do is after some changes code in PhpStorm project manually copy it to folder `some_project` and then using GIT in that folder add changes and commit them.

   Is this right to do this or there is other easy options?

So I think you got the idea what I am trying to know - some recipe of actions in this usual working case.

Comment: General info (not 100% related to your questions): https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Version+Control+Systems+Support+in+PhpStorm

Answer (score 0):

First of all, PHPStorm have its own Git manager inside of it. You do not need to add, commit, merge and so on outside of PHPStorm, you can do all of it inside PHPStorm. By default you can find your Git actions in the top right corner of your screen, and you can see what branch you're on or switch branch in the bottom right corner.

So, if you don't like new files to be created in different branches, just create the project on the Master branch and then you switch or create new branches after that.

Secondly, if you don't want the PHPStorm project files (`.idea/`) to be part of your repository, you can simply use a `.gitignore` file to ignore any of those files when you add and commit.

[Read more about ignoring files](https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/).

Personally I use PHPStorm in the following way:

1. Clone repository to local computer
2. Open new project, PHPStorm lets you select to create the project out of the existing source.
3. Handle all checkouts, merges, commits and pushes inside PHPStorm

I use a .gitignore file that make sure that the PHPStorm settings files are not included in the commits. [You can find one here](https://www.gitignore.io/api/phpstorm).

Comment: Hi! Its not a problem find out how to make commits and so on with PHPStorm inside.

1)There is no matter would you create project from master or other branch in your local repo cause when you will checkout - your project files will change!

2)I guess PHPStorm Git manager just use .git repo that in your project folder...

Comment: Why would your project files change? As I write in the answer, you use a .gitignore file to avoid committing any project files from PHPStorm.

Comment: Cause your project is the GIT Working area and when you will checkout branches - files in your phpstorm project directory will change? is not it?

I guess maybe for new future I need to create new phpstorm folder and clone there repository, then checkout to the branch for new future and after end of work on it, make merge to master or develop and delete both - phpstorm project and branch in GIT(optional). Is that will be right?

Comment: I feel like you're ignoring my messages about using a .gitignore file. The only thing PHPStorm does is create a folder called `.idea/` in your projects root directory. All Project Settings are kept in there. By using a `.gitignore` file you make sure that changes are not committed or part of the repository. Therefore, when you checkout new branches, the same Project Setting files in `.idea/` are still there.

Comment: Sorry if its look like this, finally, last questions:
1)By your words its ok have one project PHPStorm folder for ALL possible branches in that repository? Then your are not change phpstorm project in IDE but change only branch, is that right?
2)So there is no other side effect when you have same project setting in .idea/ dealing with different file list if you switch branch whatever reason and where could be сompletely different files?
3)Does the right to life have the approach I described in the previous comment?
Thank you for your patience, believe or not you are helping me a lot!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by your 3rd point. But for the other - Yes you understand it correctly.

Comment: 3rd point means making new PHPStorm project per new future, clone repository, and using only branch  new_future for commiting and pushing. After ending development proccess I could delete whole PHPStorm project and merge new_future into master in remote repository. I think this is a normal workflow using PHPStorm

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to use the code from `new_feature` branch, so you should create the phpstorm project in the git repo folder `some_project`.

For your concerns to create project in some_project folder:

> Cause if I will create it in repo folder then while changing branch
>   with checkout using GIT my project files will be changed, do I need
>   this?

Yes, when you checkout to different branch, the working directory will changed. But the project is still exist in `new_feature` branch. If necessary, you can checkout to `new_feature` branch back. And usually you are not checkout/commit/merge etc both by git command and phpstorm at the same time since phpstorm already has options for you to use git to do version control.

> And after all, if I will delete project using PhpStorm - I could
>   delete my all repository! This is unacceptable!

If you delete the whole project using PhpStorm, of cause, the whole repo will be deleted. But it’s not the risk only exist on phpstorm. If you delete the folder manually, the repo will also gone. The safer way is to **manage the git repo in remote**, such as github, bitbucket etc. Even you delete the local one, but you can still clone from remote.

Comment: Hi! First of all no matter using Git Bash console in PHPStorm project or using Git manage capabilites PHPStorm built in, you will working with same repository. Second - If your source code in branches need to be sending to a different web servers, your must have different development options in PHPStorm project and you cant achieve this if you will have one .idea folder sharing between branches. What about delete project and accidentally whole repository I understood you, thanks, now I am not afraid:)